The `'append` argument for `set-fontset-font` doesn't work
After reading Modifying-Fontsets, I started trying out the fontset fallback mechanism in Emacs 29.3.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font (font-spec :family "Courier New" :size 24))
(set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 24) nil nil)
(set-fontset-font t 'unicode (font-spec :family "Last Resort" :size 24) nil 'append)

The motivation is that

If the code point is Latin script, use "Courier New" (default font).

If the code point is Han script, use "Microsoft YaHei".

If the code point is not in the above code ranges, fallback to "Last Resort".


Now input 'ภ' (U+E20), which is Thai script.
The expect behavior is displaying the glyph  from "Last Resort", because it is not in the code ranges above.
Unfortunately, Emacs still displays . Take a look what font it used via describe-char:
harfbuzz:-outline-DokChampa-normal-normal-normal-sans-14-*-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1 (#x100)

This "DokChampa" is one of the fonts on my operating system. Consequently, Emacs still queries fonts instead of falling back to "Last Resort" as per the aforementioned rules.
Why the 'append doesn't work here? Did I misunderstand something?
P.s. A workaround is reversing the set-fontset-font's order and using 'prepend instead.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font (font-spec :family "Courier New" :size 24))
(set-fontset-font t 'unicode (font-spec :family "Last Resort" :size 24) nil 'nil)
(set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 24) nil 'prepend)

Then everything is fine, i.e. it displays 'ภ' as  via "Last Resort" and Han characters via "Microsoft YaHei".
But what I really want to know is why the 'append doesn't work!
Thanks.
